# Application package installer has stopped

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have copied my Manifest XML File. I am just not able to figure out the error. The application is running on my Redmi 1S but it is not running on my Micromax Canvas A110 I have already tried all the solutions which are already there on Stackoverflow related to this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gilpix.am"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <uses-configuration 
        android:reqTouchScreen="finger" android:reqKeyboardType="undefined"/>

     <uses-feature  
         android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />

     <uses-permission 
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


     <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true"/>




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity android:name="com.gilpix.am.Splash" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.gilpix.am.Login" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 

            >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.gilpix.am.Logind"
             android:label="@string/logind_name" 
             android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
             > 

        </activity>
          <activity android:name="com.gilpix.am.U_home"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" > 

        </activity>




           </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

clean your project and if it doesn't work than close
 the project and restart, create new apk and install

Answer (score 0):

This error is come due to different android version of your both android phones.

Please check the configuration for both the phones and change according to that in manifest.xml file

android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Thanks

Comment: Using minSdkVersion  11 means it should be running above androidVersion 3.1 and mine is 4.2 but still its not running

Comment: change android:minSdkVersion="8" and run the application it should work because it contain some of deprecated api and support by api 8